# AjaxToolkit ModalPopupExtender not on top

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a text editor embedded in a ModalPopupExtender.  It pops up, the parent page is "blacked" out, and the popup centers itself as expected.  The problem is that there are a number of controls on the parent page that paint on top of the ModalPopup.  I've tried a number of things with the z-index, but nothing seems to have any effect.

```
.modalPopup{position: absolute; background-color:#5F884C; border-width: 4px; border-color:#cccccc; border-style: solid; width: 700px; height: 330px; z-index: 9999}
```

[image]

How do I get that popup editor on top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed it was a z-index issue.  Installed Google Chrome and used their dev tools to "inspect" elements in my site.  I'd never seen these tools before, but found them astonishingly powerful at identifying all the specific attributes tied to elements of my site at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the z indices of the other items that are overlaying.  I don't recall that you should be setting the z-index on the popup style.  I think it gets set inside the control toolkit.

Try reading this link as it appears to be a similar issue they had... [ModalPopupExtender - Modifying the z-index](http://forums.asp.net/t/1303978.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Chris.  Interesting forum, and I implemented the proposed fix.  I saw the code get called, but it didn't have any effect.  I'll keep digging into this.  I did look at the z-index of the offending articles, and they are all < 10, so my 99999 should certainly cover it.  Thought maybe it was a browser issue, but I see it consistently in Firefox, IE and Safari.

Comment: Hope you figure it out, worst case maybe just try a jQueryui dialog in modal mode...[link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) that should give you all the control you need.